# Link between quick edit and Title column (linked to item with the edit menu)

Tags: 2013, quick-edit

Is it possible to use quick edit if Title column(linked to item with edit menu) is hidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it to edit items.

[image]

But you can not create new entries in the quick edit mode, because the title field has to be set in the standard list setting.

[image]

You can uncheck the required option for the title field, then you can also create new entries.

[image]

I have to mention that then the title field (if you show it in a view) has the value "**No Title**".

[image]

As far as I know...